# Drupal site redirects to installation page

Tags: redirect, drupal, installation, settings, profile

I was working on my branch this morning tweaking some CSS when all of a sudden my Drupal site went into a dead mode. I am running multi site mode and the local.settings.php in the individual sites is being ignored on load.

The parent settings.php file is also being ignored on load.

The site redirects to the installation url: http://site.local/install.php

What could have possibly went wrong and how do I go about resolving that?

Comment: I finally figured it out. For some reason it had everything to do with the settings in the sites.php

The mapping was not 100% correct even though it initially worked. I had to re-map my multi-sites domains in the sites.php and it worked. 

So if that happens, double check your multi-sites settings. Make sure domain names match and that your database credentials are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. For some reason it had everything to do with the settings in the sites.php The mapping was not 100% correct even though it initially worked. I had to re-map my multi-sites domains in the sites.php and it worked. So if that happens, double check your multi-sites settings. Make sure domain names match and that your database credentials are correct.. [see above]